# Network Flow Optimimization (Gurobi)

Tags: python, optimization, graph, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I am trying to model and solve an optimization problem, with python and gurobi optimizer. It is my first experience to solve a problem using optimizer. firstly I wrote a really big problem and add all variables and constraints, step by step. But there was problem(S) in that. so I reduce the problem to the small version, again and again. After all, now I have a very simple code:

```
from gurobipy import *

m = Model('net')
x = m.addVar(name = 'x')
y = m.addVar(name = 'y')
m.addConstr(x >= 0 and x <= 9000, name = 'flow0')
m.addConstr(y >= 0 and y <= 1000, name = 'flow1')
m.addConstr(y + x == 9990, name = 'total_flow')

m.setObjective(x *(4 + 0.6*(x/9000)) + (y * (4 + 0.6*(y/1000))), GRB.MINIMIZE)

solo = m.optimize()

if solo:
    print ('find!!!')
```

It actually is a simple network flow problem (for a graph with two nodes and two edges) I want to calculate the flow of each edge (x and y). Obviously the flow of each edge cant be negative and cant be bigger than edge capacity(x(capa) = 9000, y(capa) = 1000). and the third constraint shows the the total flow limitation on both edges. Finally, the objective function has to minimize the equation.

Now I have some question on this code:

1. why 'solo' is (None)?
2. How can I print solution variables. I used getAttr() function. but I couldn't find out the role of variables name (x, y or flow0, flow1)

3.Ive got this result. But I really cant understand this!!!!
for example: what dose it calculate in each iteration??!

Tnx in advance, and excuse for my simple question...

[image: image of results!!!!]

Comment: 1. Function `optimize()` [does not return anything](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/py_model_optimize.html).

Comment: I though solve() function in CPLEX return solution and optimize() is like that. tnx

Answer (score 0):

The `optimize()` method always returns None, see `print(help(m.optimize))`. The status of your model after calling this method is stored in `m.status` while the solution values are stored in the `.X` attribute for each variable (assumed the model was solved to optimality). To access them you can use `m.getVars()`:

```
# your model ...
m.optimize()

if m.status = GRB.OPTIMAL:
    for var in m.getVars():
        print(var.VarName, var.X)
```

Your posted log shows for each iteration of the barrier method (also known as interior point method) the objective value. See [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/barrier_logging.html) for a detailed overview.